# bash If-else on Mac

Tags: macos, bash

Why such a simple script does not work?

```
  1 for i in {1..6}
  2 do
  3     if[ "$i" -lt "3" ]
  4     then
  5         echo "a"
  6     else
  7         echo "b"
  8     fi
  9 done
```

or

```
  1 for i in {1..6}
  2 do
  3     if[ "$i" < 3 ]
  4     then
  5         echo "a"
  6     else
  7         echo "b"
  8     fi
  9 done
```

Err:

```
./test.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./test.sh: line 4: `    then'
```

Comment: what is the error you get? `if[ "$i" < 3 ]` is not valid bash

Comment: `if` and `[` must have a space between them!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need a space between `if` and `[`.

Comment: In other words, a space between the command and its first argument. As always.

Comment: thanks! How about using "<" instead of "-lt"? What's the correct way?

Comment: @JackWM: Use `-lt`. `<` does a lexicographical string comparison and needs to be escaped somehow (e.g., `\<` or `'<'`).